# Chrome dev tools CORS requests not showing in XHR filter

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When inspecting CORS XHR requests in Chrome (58.0.3029.110) development tools actual HTTP requests are not shown, only the preflight ones.

[image]

Request is shown when removing `XHR` filter
[image]

It is quite annoying. Can anything be done about this ?

Comment: same issue here chrome@68 on Mac.